# How to check ajax response against a string

Tags: javascript, ajax, responsetext

I have a very simple ajax call, but i have problems when trying to check the returned text against a string:

```
// in my php file
echo 'mystring';

// in my javascript
if((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)){
  if(request.responseText == "mystring"){
    // stuff
  }else{
    //other stuff
  }
}
```

When i try to print request.responseText it prints the expected string, "mystring". But when i try to check it, it doesn't evaluate to true ("other stuff" is executed). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your responseText contains other (non printable) characters or HTML (e.g. < > )?

Comment: Check it using Firebug in Firefox, or the inbuilt debugger in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `request.responseText.trim() === "mystring"`